# Why my HID keyboard doesn't work very well?

Tags: c++, avr, hid, atmega, custom-keyboard

I've just started programming my AtMega8 with using V-USB link: https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html. I'm trying to make a keyboard witch will be pushing CTRL+ALT. To do this I modified one of the project "HID Keys" link: https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/hidkeys.html. I added and modified:

```
//line 150, added definitions
#define KEY_DELETE 42
#define ALT_RIG    230 
#define ALT_LEF 226
#define CTRL_LEF    224
```

(I have values of definitions from this side: https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf (from page 53))

```
//line 204, modified code
static const uchar  keyReport[NUM_KEYS + 1][2] PROGMEM = {
/* none */  {0, 0},                     /* no key pressed */
/*  1 */    {0, KEY_A},
/*  2 */    {0, KEY_B},
/*  3 */    {0, KEY_C},
/*  4 */    {0, KEY_D},
/*  5 */    {0, KEY_E},
/*  6 */    {0, KEY_F},
/*  7 */    {0, KEY_G},
/*  8 */    {0, KEY_H},
/*  9 */    {0, KEY_I},
/* 10 */    {0, 0},
/* 11 */    {0, 0},
/* 12 */    {MOD_CONTROL_LEFT, ALT_RIG}, //CTRL+ALT
/* 13 */    {0, KEY_J},
/* 14 */    {0, KEY_K},
/* 15 */    {0, KEY_L},
/* 16 */    {0, KEY_M},
/* 17 */    {0, KEY_N},
};
```

Some kind of reason, "clicking" the keys (CTRL+ALT) by uC (AtMega8) does not working. (I check this by pushing at the same time (when keys from uC are (should be) pushed) the DEL key on my "true" keyboard - then the "characteristic" system management window (Windows 7) should appear.) I have no idea why this isn't work. How can I do this, that my uC will be pushing CTRL+ALT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report descriptor in the sample program defines a 2-byte report to represent a single keystroke. The first byte contains 8 bits each representing a key modifier (left ctrl, right alt, left shift etc) and the next byte is an index representing a key usage (key A, key B, key Delete, etc).

You need to logically OR the desired key modifiers in the first byte. The easiest way is to simply add them together. For example, to send Ctrl+Alt+Delete you could code:

```
{MOD_CONTROL_LEFT+MOD_ALT_LEFT, KEY_DELETE}
```

Don't forget to send {0, 0} afterwards to indicate that no keys are currently pressed.

Comment: That's working! Thank you for help. During programming occur to me one thing. It is possible to click by the uC all sequence of CTRL+ALT+DEL to display the "blue" window at PC? I was trying  to code it, but with no progress...

Comment: Oh, I wrote wrong. I mean that ctrl+alt are working (because when i push del in my real keyboard blue window appear), but all sequence of ctrl+alt+del ( `{MOD_CONTROL_LEFT+MOD_ALT_LEFT, KEY_DELETE}` ) doesn't work (blue window doesn't appear). Moreover when in the code is only del ( `{0, KEY_DELETE}` ) the del button work perectly. Only if in the code is like `{MOD_CONTROL_LEFT+MOD_ALT_LEFT, KEY_DELETE}` it isn't work like "real" ctrl+alt+delete. I was trying a lot of modifications of those code, but it isn't work. What can I do with it?

Comment: I suspect some Windows skulduggery because when I tell my home made USB keyboard to send ctrl+alt+delete to my Ubuntu 20.10 Linux system it behaves as expected. You must remember to release the keys by sending {0,0} though - otherwise the OS will think you are permanently pressing those keys.

Comment: So I tried at Win7, Win8, Win10, MS Server 2016 and the newest Ubuntu and the ctrl+alt+del by uC doesn,t work of any at this OS. I don't have an idea why it isn't working. Anyway thank you very much for help.